# UINavigationBar get white with back button

Tags: iphone

I have a set of viewcontroller that i am pushing and popping on navigationController stack.What i want to do is to hide UINavigationBar on rootviewcontroller but show on all others.So at viewwillappear of rootViewController I hide the navigation bar with self.navigationController.navigationbar.hidden = YES.But when i click back from any viewcontroller to root i see a white space inplace of bar for a split second.It seems logical as controller is popped after the viewWillAppear gets called.But when i do the hiding in viewDidAppear my whole UI shifts down.I would appreciat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `viewwilldisappear` method of the second view controller Hide the navigationcontroller again...